# SLA (Service Level Agreement) for mobility projects

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, mobile

Im looking for a template to create a SLA (Service Level Agreement). Could somebody help me?

Thanks friends.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. IOW, StackOverflow is not a law office. Please contact qualified legal counsel in your area in regards to helping you draft an SLA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, see: http://www.slatemplate.com/

## Service Level Agreement (SLA)

```
            <p><b>for: <i>Customer name</i></b></p>

            <p><b>by: <i>Company name</i></b></p>


            <p><b>Effective Date: October 6, 2012</b></p>

            <table class="slatable" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td valign="top"><p><b>Document Owner:</b></p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p><i>Company name</i></p></td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

            <p><b>Version</b></p>

            <table class="slatable" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td valign="top"><p>Version</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Date</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Description</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Author</p></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td valign="top"><p>1.0</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>01-10-2012</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Service Level Agreement</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Bob Smith</p></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td valign="top"><p>1.1</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>06-10-2012</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Service Level Agreement Revised</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Dave Jones</p></td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

            <p><b>Approval</b></p>

            <p><i>(By signing below, all Approvers agree to all terms and conditions outlined in this Agreement.)</i></p>

            <table class="slatable" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td valign="top"><p>Approvers</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Role</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Signed</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Approval Date</p></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td valign="top"><p><i>Company name</i></p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Service Provider</p></td>
                <td valign="top"></td>
                <td valign="top">08-10-2012</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td valign="top"><p>Customer</p></td>
                <td valign="top"><p>Customer</p></td>
                <td valign="top"></td>
                <td valign="top">08-10-2012</td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

            <p><b>Table of Contents</b></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_AgreementOverview">1. Agreement Overview.. 3</a></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_GoalsAndObjectives">2. Goals &amp; Objectives. 3</a></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_Stakeholders">3. Stakeholders. 3</a></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_PeriodicReview">4. Periodic Review.. 4</a></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_ServiceAgreement">5. Service Agreement 4</a></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_ServiceScope">5.1. Service Scope. 4</a></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_CustomerRequirements">5.2. Customer Requirements. 5</a></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_ServiceProviderRequirements">5.3. Service Provider Requirements. 5</a></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_ServiceAssumptions">5.4. Service Assumptions. 5</a></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_ServiceManagement">6. Service Management 6</a></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_ServiceAvailability">6.1. Service Availability. 6</a></p>

            <p><a class="slaindex" href="#_ServiceRequests">6.2. Service Requests. 6</a></p>

            <br>
            <h1 class="h1heading"><a name="_AgreementOverview">1. Agreement Overview</a></h1>

            <p>This Agreement represents a Service Level Agreement ("SLA" or "Agreement") between <i>Company name</i> and <i>Customer</i> for the provisioning of IT services required to support and sustain the <i>product or service</i>.</p>
            <br>
            <p>This Agreement remains valid until superseded by a revised agreement mutually endorsed by the stakeholders.</p>
            <br>
            <p>This Agreement outlines the parameters of all IT services covered as they are mutually understood by the primary stakeholders. This Agreement does not supersede current processes and procedures unless explicitly stated herein.</p>

            <h1 class="h1heading"><a name="_GoalsAndObjectives">2. Goals &amp; Objectives</a></h1>

            <p>The <b>purpose</b> of this Agreement is to ensure that the proper elements and commitments are in place to provide consistent IT service support and delivery to the Customer(s) by the Service Provider(s). </p>

            <p>The <b>goal</b> of this Agreement is to obtain mutual agreement for IT service provision between the Service Provider(s) and Customer(s).</p>

            <p>The <b>objectives</b> of this Agreement are to:</p>

            <ul class="serviceslist">
                <li>o Provide clear reference to service ownership, accountability, roles and/or responsibilities.</li>

                <li>o Present a clear, concise and measurable description of service provision to the customer.</li>

                <li>o Match perceptions of expected service provision with actual service support &amp; delivery.</li>
            </ul>

            <h1 class="h1heading"><a name="_Stakeholders">3. Stakeholders</a></h1>

            <p>The following Service Provider(s) and Customer(s) will be used as the basis of the Agreement and represent the <b>primary</b> <b>stakeholders</b> associated with this SLA:</p>
            <br>
            <p><b>IT Service Provider(s):</b> <i>Company name</i>. ("Provider")</p>

            <p><b>IT Customer(s):</b> <i>Customer</i> ("Customer")</p>


            <b><br>
            </b> 

            <h1 class="h1heading"><a name="_PeriodicReview">4. Periodic Review</a></h1>

            <p>This Agreement is valid from the <b>Effective Date </b>outlined herein and is valid until further notice. This Agreement should be reviewed at a minimum once per fiscal year; however, in lieu of a review during any period specified, the current Agreement will remain in effect. </p>
            <br>
            <p>The <b>Business Relationship Manager</b> ("Document Owner") is responsible for facilitating regular reviews of this document. Contents of this document may be amended as required, provided mutual agreement is obtained from the primary stakeholders and communicated to all affected parties. The Document Owner will incorporate all subsequent revisions and obtain mutual agreements / approvals as required. </p>
            <br>
            <p><b>Business Relationship Manager:</b> <i>Company name</i></p>

            <p><b>Review Period: </b>Bi-Yearly (6 months)</p>

            <p><b>Previous Review Date:</b> September 28, 2012</p>

            <p><b>Next Review Date:</b> November 7, 2012</p>

            <h1 class="h1heading"><a name="_ServiceAgreement">5. Service Agreement</a></h1>

            <p>The following detailed service parameters are the responsibility of the Service Provider in the ongoing support of this Agreement. </p>

            <h2 class="h2heading">5.1. <a name="_ServiceScope">Service Scope</a></h2>

            <p>The following Services are covered by this Agreement; </p>

            <ul class="serviceslist">
                <li>o Manned telephone support</li>

                <li>o Monitored email support</li>

                <li>o Remote assistance using Remote Desktop and a Virtual Private Network where available</li>

                <li>o Planned or Emergency Onsite assistance (extra costs apply)</li>

                <li>o Monthly system health check</li>
            </ul>


            <h2 class="h2heading">5.2.<a name="_CustomerRequirements">Customer Requirements</a></h2>

            <p><b>Customer</b> responsibilities and/or requirements in support of this Agreement include: </p>

            <ul class="serviceslist">
                <li>o Payment for all support costs at the agreed interval.</li>

                <li>o Reasonable availability of customer representative(s) when resolving a service related incident or request.</li>
            </ul>

            <h2 class="h2heading">5.3. <a name="_ServiceProviderRequirements">Service Provider Requirements</a></h2>

            <p><b>Service Provider</b> responsibilities and/or requirements in support of this Agreement include: </p>

            <ul class="serviceslist">
                <li>o Meeting response times associated with service related incidents.</li>

                <li>o Appropriate notification to Customer for all scheduled maintenance.</li>
            </ul>

            <h2 class="h2heading">5.4.<a name="_ServiceAssumptions">Service Assumptions</a></h2>

            <p>Assumptions related to in-scope services and/or components include:</p>

            <ul class="serviceslist">
                <li>o Changes to services will be communicated and documented to all stakeholders.</li>
            </ul>


             <h1 class="h1heading"><a name="_ServiceManagement">6. Service Management</a></h1>

            <p>Effective support of in-scope services is a result of maintaining consistent service levels. The following sections provide relevant details on service availability, monitoring of in-scope services and related components.</p>

            <h2 class="h2heading">6.1. <a name="_ServiceAvailability">Service </a>Availability</h2>

            <p>Coverage parameters specific to the service(s) covered in this Agreement are as follows:</p>

            <ul class="serviceslist">

                <li>o Telephone support : 9:00 A.M. to 5:00 P.M. Monday - Friday</li>

                <li>o Calls received out of office hours will be forwarded to a mobile phone and best efforts will be made to answer / action the call, however there will be a backup answer phone service</li>

                <li>o Email support: Monitored 9:00 A.M. to 5:00 P.M. Monday - Friday</li>

                <li>o Emails received outside of office hours will be collected, however no action can be guaranteed until the next working day</li>

                <li>o Onsite assistance guaranteed within 72 hours during the business week</li>

            </ul>



            <h2 class="h2heading">6.2.<a name="_ServiceRequests">Service Requests</a></h2>

            <p>In support of services outlined in this Agreement, the Service Provider will respond to service related incidents and/or requests submitted by the Customer within the following time frames: </p>

            <ul class="serviceslist">

                <li>o 0-8 hours (during business hours) for issues classified as <b>High</b> priority.</li>

                <li>o Within 48 hours for issues classified as <b>Medium</b> priority.</li>

                <li>o Within 5 working days for issues classified as <b>Low</b> priority.</li>

                <li>o Remote assistance will be provided in-line with the above timescales dependent on the priority of the support request.</li>
```